# How to get selected radio value using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i want to get radiobutton value using jquery. This is the radiobutton code. The period[count] naming is because the radiobutton is loop in array using javascript

```
<input type='radio' name='period["+count+"]' value='1' checked/>Full<input type='radio' name='period["+count+"]' value='0.5'/>Half (AM)<input type='radio' name='period["+count+"]' value='0.5'/>Half (PM)
```

Question is how do i get the total value of the checked radio button?I try this code but it give only the first value of checked radio button

```
var values2 = $("input:radio[name='period[2]']").val();
var values3 = $("input:radio[name='period[3]']").val();
```

**Edited**

This is the code to solve this problem thanks to **Aaron Saunders**

```
var x = 0;
    $("input:radio[name^='period']:checked").each(function(){
    x = x + parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find all that start with period, then add  them up

```
var x = 0;
$("input:radio[name^='period']").each(function{
        x = x + this.val();
     });
```

Comment: hi thanks for the code, however it have some syntax error. I have corrected it and now my problem solve. See the edited part. Thanks again!

Comment: yeah i just typed it up, sorry i did not really test it